# Associate employees to departments based on hierarchy tree

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to build a query to sort out department associations based on the organizational hierarchy. So if `John` is in `sales` and reports to `Jane` who reports to `Mike`. `Jane` should inherit `sales`, and `Mike` should also inherit the sales department.

**Example Table**:

```
+-------+------------+------------+
| Name  | Department | Supervisor |
+-------+------------+------------+
| John  | Sales      | Jane       |
| Jane  | Supervisor | Mike       |
| Fred  | Supervisor | Mike       |
| Alex  | Retail     | Fred       |
| Mike  | Manager    | ---        |
| Chris | Sales      | Jane       |
| Dan   | Retail     | Fred       |
+-------+------------+------------+
```

**What the tree would look like**:

[image]

**Expected Output**:

```
+-------+------------+
| Name  | Department |
+-------+------------+
| John  | Sales      |
| Jane  | Supervisor |
| Jane  | Sales      |
| Fred  | Supervisor |
| Fred  | Retail     |
| Alex  | Retail     |
| Mike  | Manager    |
| Mike  | Sales      |
| Mike  | Retail     |
| Chris | Sales      |
| Dan   | Retail     |
+-------+------------+
```

I've tried a number of things over the last 2 weeks, but have not even got close to representing the output I desire. I believe that this is going beyond my SQL knowledge, and I have no (even partially) working code to show here.

How can I achieve this?

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
    (Name varchar(5), Department varchar(10), Supervisor varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Employees
    (Name, Department,Supervisor)
VALUES
    ('John', 'Sales', 'Jane'),
    ('Jane', 'Supervisor', 'Mike'),
    ('Fred', 'Supervisor', 'Mike'),
    ('Alex', 'Retail', 'Fred'),
    ('Mike', 'Manager', '---'),
    ('Chris', 'Sales', 'Jane'),
    ('Dan', 'Retail', 'Fred')
;
```

Comment: Can you provide some ddl for your sample data? Also, shouldn't Mike also inherit Supervisor?

Comment: @SeanLange You are correct, Mike would inherit that. In this case I have been trying to exclude "management" type departments from the hierarchy. I think I added when you needed.

Comment: so this is mysql it looks like, no?

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Comment: @scsimon MS-SQL

Comment: @DouglasGaskell please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with <kbd>CTE using recursion</kbd>.

**[<kbd>Link on MSDN</kbd>](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)** to know more about recursive CTE

**Query below**

```
--CREATE TABLE Employees
--    (Name varchar(5), Department varchar(10), Supervisor varchar(4))
--;

--INSERT INTO Employees
--    (Name, Department, Supervisor)
--VALUES
--    ('John', 'Sales', 'Jane'),
--    ('Jane', 'Supervisor', 'Mike'),
--    ('Fred', 'Supervisor', 'Mike'),
--    ('Alex', 'Retail', 'Fred'),
--    ('Mike', 'Manager', '---'),
--    ('Chris', 'Sales', 'Jane'),
--    ('Dan', 'Retail', 'Fred')
--;

WITH user_cte AS (
SELECT Name, Department,Supervisor
FROM Employees
WHERE Department ='Retail' or Department='Sales'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
t.Name, ucte.Department,t.Supervisor
FROM Employees t
INNER JOIN user_cte ucte ON ucte.Supervisor = t.Name
)
SELECT DISTINCT Name,Department
FROM user_cte
UNION 
SELECT Name, Department 
FROM Employees
GO
```

**Explanation:**

Recursive CTEs are a common programming construct in SQL server. Important thing to note is that by default they nest up to 100 levels. If you need to nest deeper use [<kbd>`MAXRECURSION`</kbd>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) query hint

CTE alone does not give you the complete output and you need to add up the missing rows from original table using `UNION` expression.

Comment: Checking now, the actual tables I have are a bit more complex/annoying so this will take a few minutes to recreate this, and probably several minutes to run. Will I need to modify this to work with more than 3 levels of hierarchy, or does it sort that out itself? Additionally, if you are up to it, an explanation of what that query is doing would be great

Comment: This will not work if there are more hierarchies in the dataset.

Comment: Dhruv, any idea how bad the performance on this might be? The table is ~4400 employees and it's been running for ~15 minutes now.

Comment: This is a good answer but the formatting of that query is painful. If you remove the where clause in the first query of your cte it returns exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Performance will be good if you have an index covering the columns `Supervisor` and `Name`. Better idea would be to use an integer key column say `ID` on the table and instead of supervisor use `supervisorID`